# Perl issue with storing url in variable

Tags: perl, url, escaping

I am relatively new to Perl. I am trying to store a URL in a variable. Here's my code:

```
my $port = qx{/usr/bin/perl get_port.pl};
print $port;
my $url = "http://localhost:$port/cds/ws/CDS";
print "\n$url\n";
```

This gives me the below output:

```
4578
/cds/ws/CDS
```

So the `get_port.pl` script is giving me the port correctly but the URL isn't getting stored properly. I believe there's some issue with the slash `/` but I am not sure how to get around it. I have tried escaping it with backslash and I have also tried `qq{}` but it keeps giving the same output.

Please advise.

Output for `perl get_port.pl | od -a`

`0000000  nl   4   5   7   8  nl
0000006`

Comment: `perl yourscript.pl | hexdump -C` might be helpful. (and how about `qx{}`?)

Comment: Please post the actual code of an example that we can run. The code in the question contains a fatal syntax error (the `qx` is not terminated), so it is not the code you ran to produce your results (because it won't run, period). Also, even if we could run it, we don't have your `get_port.pl` program, so we would get different results for reasons completely unrelated to your question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Dave. I have modified it as per latest suggestions and it still doesn't work. I will post the get_port.pl code shortly. It's making some calls to an internal API after downloading java & setting a couple of env variables.

Comment: Can you show the result of `/usr/bin/perl get_port.pl | od -c` ?

Comment: I'm sorry the get_port.pl has a lot of internal code which I don't think I should post here. However, @Borodin's answer worked for me.

Comment: @manpreetbhamba: The command that tivn asked you to run displays the *output* of your program, which is just a decimal number with some formatting. The contents of the code are safe. I think using `od -a` would be a little better though. Please would you do that for us? I realise you are happy with my solution but I would like to see what the problem is

Comment: Sure @Borodin. I have added the output to my question.

Comment: Okay thanks. Then you have shown only part of the output of your program there is a line `http://localhost:` before that, and we have been trying to fathom why it wasn't being printed

Comment: Sorry but I thought you wanted me to run the script that I am calling in the above code that only prints the port not the full url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is noithing wrong with your `$url` string. The problem is almost certainly that the `$port` string contains carriage-return characters. Presumably you are working on Windows?

Try this code instead, which extracts the first string of digits it finds in the value returned by `get_port.pl` and discards everything else.

```
my ($port) = qx{/usr/bin/perl get_port.pl} =~ /(\d+)/;
print $port, "\n";
my $url = "http://localhost:$port/cds/ws/CDS";
print $url, "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Сухой27 I think was trying to point out, you can use other character besides '/' with qx, to simplify syntax and then you don't have to escape the slashes.

I also added a default port 8080 in case get_port.pl does not exist.

This seems to work properly.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# make 8080 the default port
my $port = qx{/usr/bin/perl get_port.pl} || 8080;
print $port;
my $url = "http://localhost:$port/cds/ws/CDS";
print "\n$url\n";
```

**output**

```
paul@ki6cq:~/SO$ ./so1.pl 
Can't open perl script "get_port.pl": No such file or directory
8080
http://localhost:8080/cds/ws/CDS
```

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work for me. Still getting the same output. I do not understand how changing the code for getting port would affect how the url is being stored. Thanks anyways!

Comment: running `perl -v` here yields `v5.20.2`.  However, the behavior reported isn't making much sense to me.  It should be printing "http://..." instead of omitting the beginning and providing only the file path.